# How does ngIf directive alter detection change cycle?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngif-detectionchange

I have `testToggle` component that can change its height because of binding to some property inside it. It has sibling `testParent` component that is flex to take rest of height and it has child `testChild` component that has binding to `testParent` height. When `testParent` has *ngIf directive with true expression, when `testToggle` change property bound to its height, I got:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked.

After logging lifecycle hook order of components, I found something strange:

```
No ngIf used                              testParent has ngIf with expression true

testToggle: DoCheck                       testToggle: DoCheck
testParent: DoCheck                       testParent: DoCheck
testToggle: AfterContentChecked           testParent: AfterContentChecked
testParent: AfterContentChecked              testChild: DoCheck
   testChild: DoCheck                        testChild: AfterContentChecked
   testChild: AfterContentChecked            testChild: AfterViewChecked
   testChild: AfterViewChecked            testParent: AfterViewChecked
testToggle: AfterViewChecked              testToggle: AfterContentChecked
testParent: AfterViewChecked              testToggle: AfterViewChecked
```

Apparently, right example throw ExpressionChanged because whole `testParent` cycle has ended before `testToggle` could update its binding (that would change its height, and therefore change `testParent` height).

I would like to know why does component that is added dynamically using ngIf finish its whole lifecycle before it continue normally through component tree?